# Can't select the Lite plan for IBM Cloud Db2

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

I just started the data engineering certificate of IBM, and at one point we had to create an IBM Cloud Lite account.

After creating the account I went ahead and tried to create a **Db2 instance**. But when selecting a plan, according to the tutorial in the IBM certificate I should be able to choose the *lite plan*, but I only get the *standard* or the *enterprise* plan ([Db2 plans available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76Wy1.png)) even though in the catalog it says that the **Db2 instance** is *Lite* and *Free* ([Db2 instance in IBM Catalog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RysVv.png)).

I tried with a lite account created with my school mail address and with my personal mail address and the lite plan isn't available for either one.

Can anyone help me with this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Try a different region, for example, Dallas or London, to see if the lite plan is available. Works for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a question with related answer in the [Db2 on Cloud FAQ for the lite plan](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Db2onCloud?topic=Db2onCloud-free_plan#fp_availability):

> #### Regional availability
>
> The Lite plan is available in the Dallas and London regions. If you do not see the Lite plan listed in the catalog, select either Dallas or London region.

As stated in the comment above, try to switch to a different region.